# I want to put the context widget in a string variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put the context widget in a string variable like that

```
String check = "$context.widget";
```

But I do it like that:

```
Widget checks = context.widget;
String check = "$checks";
```

as the . when i type it between  "" the compiler just read context as a variable and .widget as  a text so please advice

Comment: Please try using this approach, as I believe it will be helpful for your situation: `String check = checks.toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you're evaluating an identifier, so you should use curly braces:

```dart
String check= "${context.widget}";
```

from dart docs:
You can use ${} to interpolate the value of Dart expressions within strings. The curly braces can be omitted when evaluating identifiers:

```dart
const string = 'dartlang';
print('$string has ${string.length} letters'); // dartlang has 8 letters
```